# JavaScript onclick event in a jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am trying to select values on Jsp dynamically from Jsp in a dropdown list based on slection of another dropdown.
For example:I have two drop down1-A,B and drop down2 has values 1 to 10.
So when I select A i want 5 values from dropdown to be selected dynamically based on onclick event.Is it possible??

Comment: I know How to retrieve from database but finding difficulty in invoking the function to connect to database through javascript onclick event

Comment: use ajax to connect to a servlet which will connect to the db

Answer (score 0):

First, this has nothing to do with JSP. It's client side interaction and you need to use JavaScript to manage this.

If you have dropdown using `<select>` you need to capture `change` event for the first dropdown - triggered everythime when the value of the dropdown changes.

To make the code easier to read and avoid cross browsers issues, you may use jQuery to take care of this  situation.

Hence, if you have a `<select>` element with ID set to say `dropdown1` you can try this:

```
jQuery("#dropdown1").change(function () {

    var selectedValue = jQuery(this).val();

    // Now use to value to do other stufffs

});
```

However, if you are having a 'dropdown' for the second one it's not possible to select multiple values. One basic option is to convert this dropdown into a list and enable multiple slection using `multiple="multiple"` (Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp)

That is, you just need to use `<select multiple="multiple">`

Now, I am not aware of your requirement and logic to pick up which particular values of the second dropdown for each item of the first dropdown. But, it seems you need to apply your own logic here.

However, let's consider that for value `A' of dropdown1 the selected values in dropdown2 will be '1', '2' and '4'; for value`B' of dropdown1 the selected values in dropdown2 will be '2', '5' and '6','8' and '10' you can use code like this:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function () {
    jQuery("#dropdown1").change(function () {

        var selectedValue = jQuery(this).val(),
            mappedValues = {
                "A": {"1": true, "2": true, "4": true}, 
                "B": {"2": true, "5": true, "6": true, "8": true, "10": true}
            },
            selectedMappedValues = mappedValues[selectedValue] || {},
            dropdown2 = jQuery("#dropdown2"),
            dropdown2Options = dropdown2.find('option'),
            dropdown2Option;

         dropdown2Options.prop('selected', false);
         dropdown2Options.each(function () {
            dropdown2Option = jQuery(this);
            if (selectedMappedValues[dropdown2Option.val()]) {
                dropdown2Option.prop('selected', true);
            }
         });     

    });
});
```

Live Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sudipto/uzmbko17/

Answer (score 0):

try this.
this jsp code.

```
<select id="dropdown1" name="dropdown1" onchange="selectValue()">
  <option  value="a">A</option>
  <option  value="b">B</option>
</select>
<select id="dropdown2" name="dropdown2">
  <option  value="a1">1</option>
  <option  value="a2">2</option>
  <option  value="a3">3</option>
  <option  value="a4">4</option>
  <option  value="a5">5</option>
  <option  value="a6">6</option>
  <option  value="a7">7</option>
  <option  value="a8">8</option>
  <option  value="a9">9</option>
  <option  value="a10">10</option>
</select>
```

this is javascript function

```
function selectValue(){
if(document.getElementById("dropdown1").value == a){
 document.getElementById("dropdown2").value = a5;
}
}
```

thats all.thanx.